# Implicit truthiness of return type

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that returns a list

```
def get_something() -> List[str]:
    return ['abc']
```

later I have a function that (among other things) returns a `bool` based on this list being empty or not. Based on [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommendation of

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false

I wanted to write something like

```
def check_something_implicit() -> bool:
    return get_something()  # implicit truthiness of returned list
```

but the type checker will [return an error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=bc078327e38ed5a24430cefb7e338067) like

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[str]", expected "bool")
```

Instead I have to write an explicit version like

```
def check_something_explicit() -> bool:
    return len(get_something()) > 0

# or

def check_something_explicit() -> bool:
    return get_something() != []
```

Is there a way to use implicit truthiness in a return statement context?

Comment: Type checker is correct in that return value is not bool. You are typing with explicit bool, so you cannot use implicit value. You can use `bool(get_something())` for most clarity, imho.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I think that's the version I'll go with, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @matszwecja, you simply cast your list to a boolean, i.e.

```
def check_something_explicit() -> bool:
    return bool(get_something())
```

I think using implicit booleanness would actually be to avoid the `check_something_explicit` function altogether. In your code this would look like this for example:

```
# instead of this
if check_something_implicit():
    # some further operations

# directly use this
if get_something():
    # some further operations
```